# Is there a way for Interaction Studio to generate an Engagement Score from CRM fields before a Lead/Contact Id has known website visit behaviors?

Tags: marketing-cloud, lead-conversion, sales-cloud, web2lead, interaction-studio

The use case that we want to apply here is to use Interaction Studio (Marketing Cloud Personalization) to generate an Engagement Score for a Lead from Sales Cloud using specific fields and the weightage we assign in Interaction Studio KPI's.

We are looking for a way for these fields and weightage to assign an engagement score **BEFORE** the CRM Lead is a known user on the website. We have successfully integrated Salesforce CRM.

So far, it appears that an Engagement Score will not generate until Interaction Studio has a web activity and User ID as a result of website visits.

Has anyone discovered or developed a way around this? I'm still searching Evergage documentation and have reached out to Salesforce as well, without much help so far.

An idea is to simulate a web activity for Leads (with ContactKeys) from CRM but I'm not sure how we'd go about that.

Any ideas, links, or documentation would be helpful and much appreciated. Thanks!